# Invalid value of type 'numpy.float64' received for the 'y' property of scatter

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly-python, scipy-optimize

I am having the subject error when I try to use add_trace function from plotly. I have 2 independent variables (x1 and x2) and a dependent variable(y). I used curve_fit for data fitting and want to add a trace line to the graph. Be noted this is a random dataset so the result doesn't make sense at all.

Below is the code and the error. Any advice or suggestion would be greatly appreciated

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go  
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

np.random.seed(0)
x1 = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)
x2 = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)
y = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)

def func(x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
    return (a * x[0]**3 + b * x[0]**2 + c * x[0]) + (d * x[1]**3 + e * x[1]**2 + f * x[1]) + g

def inv(x1, x2, y):
    (a, b, c, d, e, f, g), _ = curve_fit(func, np.stack([x1, x2]), y)

    # create graph
    x3 = [sum(i) for i in zip(x1, x2 )]  
    x = np.linspace(min(x3), max(y), 1000)

    fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=x3, y=y, name='data'))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=func(x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g), name='fit'))
    fig.show()
    
    return  (a, b, c, d, e, f, g)

inv(x1, x2, y)

ValueError: 
Invalid value of type 'numpy.float64' received for the 'y' property of scatter
    Received value: 49.464592654826

The 'y' property is an array that may be specified as a tuple,
list, numpy array, or pandas Series
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in you pass a single value as parameter `y` to plotly.
This is not supported anymore since version 3 see [migration-guide-plotly](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/migration-guide.md#data-array-properties-may-not-be-specified-as-scalars).

So in your case the simple fix would be to replace  `fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=func(x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g), name='fit'))` with `fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=[func(x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g)], name='fit'))`.

I had a very similar problem lately where the predictions of my models could either be a list or a number. For this I used `np.array(current_predictions)` as parameter for `y`.

I know this won't help you anymore but maybe someone else stumbles upon it :)

Comment: Thanks Markus Schreiber, this is helpful

Comment: does anyone know why though? seems really stupid as I am able to set a float as x value but not as y value.